# Права или привилегии в последних достижениях

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В подсказке кнопки последних достижений вверху страницы указаны "права", но как я понимаю, должны быть "привилегии":

[image: правилегии]

Ну и вместо "значков" должны быть "знаки" вроде.